# Using multilevel json to generate a JWT using .claim() in Java

Tags: java, oauth, jwt

I'm trying to generate a JWT within my automation test which is using rest assured so is Java based. Below is an example of what the payload structure is like when I decode the token from the application (taken from JSON example):

```
"problems": [{
    "Diabetes":[{
        "medications":[{
            "medicationsClasses":[{
                "className":[{
                    "associatedDrug":[{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }],
                    "associatedDrug#2":[{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }]
                }],
                "className2":[{
                    "associatedDrug":[{
                        "name":"asprin",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }],
                    "associatedDrug#2":[{
                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"500 mg"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "labs":[{
            "missing_field": "missing_value"
        }]
    }],
    "Asthma":[{}]
}]}
```

Is there a way which I can enter the child fields using JWTs claim() function or a way in which I can point it to a JSON file, from my expereince I wasn't able to do that from the .claim() function?

Answer (score 0):

I used JSON objects and lists for use in the `claim` function

Comment: Please edit your question and include these details there, or past as a comment.